# finding area and centre of stones

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I want to find area and center of these stones.
but some of them can not be found.
[image]

here are codes

```
I=imread('E:/2.png');
level = graythresh(I);
BW = im2bw(I,level);
se = strel('disk',2);
bw1 = imclose(BW,se);
bw1 = imfill(BW,'holes');

bwa=bwareaopen(bw1,25);
cc = bwconncomp(bwa)
stat = regionprops(cc,'centroid','Area');
ss=[stat.Area];
imshow(I); hold on;
 for x = 1: numel(stat)
    plot(stat(x).Centroid(1),stat(x).Centroid(2), 'wp','MarkerSize',6,'MarkerFaceColor','b');
  end
figure, imshow(bwa)
```

result is here:
[image]

and this is black and white pic;
[image]
some of these stones can not be separated.
is there any idea for it?

Comment: I couldn't tell you how many stones there are _by looking at the picture_! I'd suggest to erode that last image a bit, but your problem is ill-defined, IMO.

Comment: some of stones have been stuck together and some of them are not bright enough to separate.I want to know how can I separate them,

Comment: The Holy Grail of image processing: counting rocks.

Comment: the term "image segmentation" may lead to some ideas..

Comment: let's ask my whole question
I want to find stones with specific area, for example with are of 40
how can I find it?

Comment: This is basically an image segmentation problem.  This has been an unsolved problem for many years.  No technique can get every example or situation right.  I would do what chappjc suggested where you should erode the picture.  Personally I would do an opening to get rid of any spurious noisy pixels.  If you want to segment out those rocks that have a width of 40, you can specify `BoundingBox` as an additional parameter into the `regionprops` function then use the width parameters (last two values) to determine whether you should accept or reject each shape.

Comment: Would bilateral filter be useful here? Edge-preservation is important because some stones are merely separated by a very thin slice of dark pixels. http://imageprocessingblog.com/bilateral-filtering/

Answer (score 2):

Erode stones until you separated them, find segments via connected components (e.g. findContours), set centers, then apply flood fill seeding floods at the centers in the original BW image (before erosion) to gracefully define segments. “Gracefully” means that floods should not ‘leak' into another (possibly connected) segment since it will be already filled with a different label. You may want to play with the parameters of [floodFIll](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=floodfill#cv.FloodFill) to tune up your segmentation. I did not have time to do this.

```
// separate stones
Mat Ibw = imread("bw.png", 0);
imshow("bw", Ibw);
int w=Ibw.cols, h=Ibw.rows;
int ERODE_SZ = 20;
Mat kernel = getStructuringElement( cv::MORPH_RECT, Size(ERODE_SZ, ERODE_SZ));
Mat Ierode;
erode(Ibw, Ierode, kernel);
imshow("erode", Ierode); imwrite("erode.png", Ierode);
vector<vector<Point> > contours;
Mat hierarchy;
Mat Icc = Ierode.clone();
findContours(Icc, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

// find centers
Mat Icenters = Ibw.clone();
int sz = contours.size();
vector<Point> centers(sz);
for (int i=0; i<sz; ++i) {
     if (i==0)
         centers[i] = Point2f(0.f, 0.f);
     int area = contours[i].size();
     for (int j=0; j<area; j++) {
         centers[i]+=contours[i][j];
     }
     centers[i]*=1.0/area;
     circle(Icenters, centers[i], 3, 100, 3);
}
imshow("centers", Icenters);imwrite("erode.png", Ierode);

// find segments
Mat Iseg = Ibw.clone();
RNG rng( 0xFFFFFFFF );
for (int i=0; i<sz; ++i) {
    floodFill(Iseg, centers[i], rng.uniform(100, 200));
    circle(Iseg, centers[i], 3, 0, 1);
}
imshow("seg", Iseg); imwrite("result.png", Iseg);
waitKey();
```

[image]

Comment: I will try this, and see what can I find,,
pretty thanks

Comment: Keep in mind this was done in C++ and OpenCV.  However, looking at the code in hindsight, you can easily reproduce this in MATLAB.

Comment: That is true. I guess a central idea here is to start thinking  about image processing as happening in parallel from segment centers instead of some process that relies on sweeping the image

Comment: As an improvement consider running the flood fill on the eroded image, adding segment labels to the original thresholded image and then continuing with watershed